# How to traverse along an array to find the next filled value in PHP?

Tags: php, time-series

For example, when working with time series data like the following:

```
[2022-07-10] => 38943
[2022-07-11] => 42259
[2022-07-12] => 45575
[2022-07-13] => null
[2022-07-14] => null
[2022-07-15] => 53845
[2022-07-16] => 57142
```

There might be some "holes" in the data. You might find it useful to get the next or last non-empty value.

Answer (score -1):

The following function will find the next "filled" value in an array.

- `$data` The array you'd like to traverse.
- `$from` The index you'd like to start from. Most likely, you are using this function while looping over an array.
- `$direction` The direction can be used as -1 as last or +1 as next.

The function:

```
// Traverse along an array in a specified direction to find the next value that is not null
private function getNextFilledValue(array $data, int $from, int $direction = +1) {
    for($offset = 1;; $offset++) {
        // Do not consider values outside of the array bounds
        // This could also be written within the second for condition
        if($offset < 0) return 0;
        if($offset >= count($data)) return null;

        // Calculate the offset taking the direction into account
        $directedOffset = $offset * $direction;

        // If a value is found, return it, otherwise continue traveling along the array
        if(!is_null($data[$from + $directedOffset])) {
            return $data[$from + $directedOffset];
        }
    }
}
```

You could also change the condition at `if(!is_null($da...` to use a different check to detect a "filled" value.

Note: When trying to find the **last** filled value, it would likely be easier for you to simply save the last valid value while looping.

```
$lastValid;

foreach($array as $value) {
    if(isValid($lastValid)) {
        $lastValid = $value;
    }

    $value = $lastValid;

    // Do something with the current value
}
```